# Pythonic way to access data from a tuple?

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn, tuples

I am working with `sklearn`'s [partial_dependency](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.partial_dependence.html) function. I am aware of the plot_partial_dependency function, but I am not interested in using it.

I want to, for each feature in my dataset, determine the average dependency to create a dict of features and their average dependency. I have the ability to do this, but quite frankly, the solution is rather verbose with how I am accessing the `tuple` that is returned from `partial_dependency`. Is there a more pythonic way to get the `average` of the first `ndarray` returned in the tuple?

Code below:

```
feature_dict = {}

for feature in X_test.columns:
    results = partial_dependence(mlp, X_test, features=feature, 
                                percentiles=(0.001, 0.999), grid_resolution=25)
    lists = [x for x in results]
    yx = lists[0]
    y=yx[0]
    feature_dict[feature] = np.avg(y)
```

This works, as if I `print(feature_dict)` I get:

`{'Feature0': 0.8403025353927007, 'Feature1': 0.7832550769883906, 'Feature2': 0.8396910956294878, 'Feature3': 0.6738822611060408, 'Feature4': 0.45209427548019937}`

However, the code isn't pythonic and is a confusing way to access the tuple released from the `partial_dependence` function. What can I do for a more simple solution?

Comment: Have you tried using the attribute `results.averaged_predictions` instead of the direct output of `results`?

Comment: @G.Anderson, In trying to make this minimal, I did not include the total code base which does have me doing some more things (special plots) with these values. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"...is a confusing way to access the tuple released from the `partial_dependence` function."*

If `results` is a tuple, then `[x for x in results]` could just be `results = list(results)`. But list items can be accessed by index just like tuples. So there's no need to convert it to a tuple first.

You're then doing `yx = lists[0]` which refers to the first part of the return value of [`partial_dependence()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.partial_dependence.html). That's `averaged_predictions`. So that line could have been just `yx = results.averaged_predictions`.

Then, `y=yx[0]` which is the first element of the first part of the partial_dependence return value. That would be `y = results.averaged_predictions[0]`.

Putting all that together, the code becomes:

```py
feature_dict = {}

for feature in X_test.columns:
    results = partial_dependence(mlp, X_test, features=feature, 
                                 percentiles=(0.001, 0.999), grid_resolution=25)
    y = results.averaged_predictions[0]
    feature_dict[feature] = np.avg(y)
```

And unless you're processing `y` further, it doesn't need to be assigned separately:

```py
for feature in X_test.columns:
    results = partial_dependence(mlp, X_test, features=feature, 
                                 percentiles=(0.001, 0.999), grid_resolution=25)
    feature_dict[feature] = np.avg(results.averaged_predictions[0])
```

---

Next step optional, and *discouraged* due to how it looks - you could make that whole loop a large almost-unreadable dictionary comprehension:

```py
feature_dict = {
    feature: np.avg(
                partial_dependence(mlp, X_test,
                                   features=feature, 
                                   percentiles=(0.001, 0.999),
                                   grid_resolution=25
                ).averaged_predictions[0])
    for feature in X_test.columns
}
```